# Excel calculation vs. python, and decimal usage

Tags: python, excel, decimal

Sorry, a few parts to this question. I need to run calculations with very accurate precision.

I am playing around with Decimal in python and trying to verify the calculations. I believe to use the actual number, you need to have the number as a string right? I am running the below code.

1) For A I have it as a float, and B I have it as a string. I get different numbers when I square them, is that because of floating point arithmetic? Is B ** 2 more correct?

2) On the last print statement, I am trying to get the square root, but end up with a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Decimal' and 'float'`. Why is that?

3) Lastly when I try to verify 100.0897463 squared in excel, I get an answer of 10017.95731439840000000000. Is the difference just due to rounding? What is an effective way of verifying floating point vs. decimal calculations if not through something like excel?

```
A = decimal.Decimal(100.0897463)
B = decimal.Decimal('100.0897463')
print A ** 2
print B ** 2
print B ** .5
```

Gets me these to numbers,

```
10017.95731439836401246854725
10017.95731439836369
```

Interestingly, when I run the code like this, I get the exact same numbers for both, and they not either of the results from printing without the decimal precision. Why would that be?

```
print "%.20f" % A ** 2
print "%.20f" % B ** 2
```

Results in:

```
10017.95731439836345089134
10017.95731439836345089134
```

Comment: Using Excel to verify Python calculations is a bad idea since it has its own proprietary decimal rounding which departs from IEEE standards (albeit in minor ways). Note that you could always forget the decimal point and just compute `1000897463**2` as an integer (yielding `1001795731439836369`). That will have no round-off error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) For A I have it as a float, and B I have it as a string. I get different numbers when I square them, is that because of floating point arithmetic? Is B ** 2 more correct?

B ** 2 is more correct.  A is imprecise because you are initializing the `Decimal` from a `float` and not a string.

> 2) On the last print statement, I am trying to get the square root, but end up with a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Decimal' and 'float'. Why is that?

Because `Decimal`’s implementation of `__pow__` expects the parameter to be of the same type.  i.e., also a `Decimal`

```
    B ** decimal.Decimal('0.5') 
    # this works because B and the exponent are now of the same type
```

> 3) Lastly when I try to verify 100.0897463 squared in excel, I get an answer of 10017.95731439840000000000. Is the difference just due to rounding? What is an effective way of verifying floating point vs. decimal calculations if not through something like excel

Doing the math by hand.  In this case, you can see that the last digit of the number you are squaring is `3` which means that its square should end in a `9`.  This strongly implies that excel also has rounding/precision issues (expected).

4. Your other question

It looks like `%f` is converting the `Decimal` to a float before printing.  In order to alleviate this, print with `%s`:

```
print '%s' % (A ** 2,)
print '%s' % (B ** 2,)
```

To see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

For (1), I think the discrepancy is that, for 'A', the value you are feeding into `decimal.Decimal()` is already in binary floating point format.  For `B`, `decimal.Decimal` creates a representation from a string, so it may be more of what you expect.

```
# The value is already in binary floating point format.
A = decimal.Decimal(100.0897463)

# Conversion from string
B = decimal.Decimal("100.0897463")
```

For (2), `decimal.Decimal` objects support the `**` operator only with other `Decimal` objects.  So the following will work:

```
print B ** decimal.Decimal("0.5")
```

For (3), I'm not sure what Excel does, but I verified like this:

```
# Essentially, multiply by 1 billion so that we only need to work with
# integers.
x = 1000897463  
print x ** 2
# This gives: 1001795731439836369L
```

So, you know `10017.95731439836369` is the exact value.  There are probably more ways to do this.

BTW, `print "%f" % value` converts the value to Python's floating point representation.